# PHP MYSQL Error: Unknown column 'status' in 'where clause'

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am getting an error `Error 1054: Unknown column 'status' in 'where clause'` when running the below query from PHP. It runs ok from phpMyAdmin, mysql, and Toad for Mysql and status is an existing column in `product_to_supplier` table.

```sql
( 
SELECT 
    pts.supplier_id AS supplier_id,
    CASE 
        WHEN IFNULL( ps.price, 0 ) > 1 AND IFNULL ( ps.price, 0 ) < pts.price THEN ps.price 
        ELSE pts.price 
    END AS price 
FROM egycart.`product_to_supplier` pts
         LEFT JOIN egycart.`product_special` ps ON pts.product_id = ps.product_id AND pts.supplier_id = ps.supplier_id 
WHERE pts.product_id = '887'
AND pts.status = '887' 
AND pts.quantity >0 
ORDER BY price 
) 
UNION DISTINCT 
( 
SELECT 
    pts.supplier_id AS supplier_id, 
    CASE 
        WHEN IFNULL( ps.price, 0 ) >1 AND IFNULL( ps.price, 0 ) < pts.price THEN ps.price 
    ELSE pts.price 
END AS price 
FROM product_to_supplier pts 
         LEFT JOIN product_special ps ON pts.product_id = ps.product_id AND pts.supplier_id = ps.supplier_id 
WHERE pts.product_id = '887' 
AND pts.status = '887' 
ORDER BY price 
) 
LIMIT 0 , 1
```

I have looked around, but I couldn't find a good answer.

Thanks

Comment: can you give us a little more of the php file? Perhaps the block where the statement gets prepared and executed besides just the query?

Comment: You are probably running the query against different dbs. Why do you have a db name in the first `product_to_supplier` reference but not in the second?

Comment: Firstly try to run SELECTs separately, which is wrong?

Comment: @rsanchez: Thank you very much for the note, i added the db name and the query worked fine.

Comment: @Cristian Cavalli: i am modifying opencart "opencart.com" code to add a new functionality.

Comment: @jim: i built the query on phpMyAdmin then moved it to the code.

Thank you guys.

Answer (score 0):

@rsanchez: Thank you very much for the note, i added the db name and the query worked fine.